# Custom Alertdialog is coming over soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I have extended the AlertDialog class to create a popup view in the Bottom of the screen, like a little notification for the user inside the app. To do so I modified a few of the Window properties of the dialog. Here is a sample code :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams win = getWindow().getAttributes();
        win.dimAmount = 0.0F;
        win.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        win.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        win.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        win.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        win.windowAnimations = R.style.PopUpAnimation;
getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) win);
```

However, when the soft keyboard pops up, the popup window remains on top of the keyboard. How do I make the dialog be behind the softkeyboard, or alternatively, how can I detect when the keyboard is visible on the screen?

Comment: Unfortunately, Android does not provide a clear way to know if the software keyboard is open, and that's a big problem. So I'd recommend you not to use the lower part of the screen for your notifications.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can send the window of the popup behind the keyboard?